# Evaluate a range based on presence of substring in adjacent fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My dataset has series of columns with the pattern

- a question column, tagged with one of many possible tags. For example:

  *What is your year in school (tag - A, B, C)*
- a response column with some standard series of responses.

I need to aggregate the results  by tag for each row - for example, the lowest-number response for all questions in the row tagged with *B*.

Have been asked to do this in Excel on a mac - normally I would do it in R but that's not going to work this time.

Thanks for any guidance!

Edited to add:

[image]

Didn't realize I could drop an image here. So, for example, I would like to be able to see that for questions tagged *C*, the low response was "2".

Comment: Sample data with your excel set up showing your desired output will go a long way here. Thanks

Comment: @urdearboy didn't realize I could drop an image here. Edited, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for a quick and dirty, one-off solution, you could just drop in some helper formulas to the right of the actual data. You'd have one per target tag, ex.
`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("A",A2)), "", 1)`

Just adjust the target cells and search values and then you'll have a 1 in the row if it contains the target flag, and the sum of that column is the # of rows with the target flag. To enable getting the lowest response # with a flag swap the `1` with the response # (wherever that is) and then the `MIN` of the column will be what 're looking for (and the `MAX` would be largest response #, `COUNT` would get the # of responses with the tag).

Comment: Thanks - but there are a couple hundred question/response pairs and dozens of tags that need to be evaluated.

Comment: The volume of question/response pairs wouldn't be that bad (assuming they're row-wise you just auto-extend the formulas to the end of the data). For the multiple tags, what you can do is have the logic point to a series of cells to get the lookup values (i.e. swap `"A"` for `E$1`). Then you could have the tags running across the top of the sheet and just drag the formulas to the right to change which tag to look for. Just make sure to put `$` in front of the other column references so that those are held constant (ex. `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(E$1,$A2)),"",1)`

Comment: The other alternative would be going to a macro, but that seems like more work than it's worth in this case

Comment: Think this'll be a place to start. Thanks kindly!